# How do I change the Firebase URL in a backbone.js application

Tags: backbone.js, firebase, backbonefire

I'm creating a backbone application that is divided into months.
In my firebase the month is the parent node, and under that I have key\value pairs that I need.

What I can't figure out is how to change the month and trigger everything updating.
eg if I hardcode my url it's something like

`https://blinding-fire-XXXX.firebaseio.com/Application/Month1`

which is fine for getting data for Month1 , but how should I update my application to get data for Month2?

I'm assuming I should be able to use the base url (without Month1) and some sort of filter, but I just can't figure it out.

I have tried , 'restarting' the app when the user selects a different Month and this works the first time a month is shown, but if they return to a previously selected month , I get an empty list.

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction!

Comment: Without seeing your code, it's tricky to help. See [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: *"how to change the month and trigger everything updating. eg if I hardcode my url it's something like"* - change month in the application or firebase..? hardcode something in application or firebase..? Your question isn't clear try to rephrase it...

Answer (score 0):

[**You can use the `urlRoot` property**](https://github.com/firebase/backbonefire#urlroot) to create a new `Firebase.Model` based on the base url and the model's `id`.

```
var Month = Backbone.Firebase.Model.extend({
  urlRoot: 'https://<my-firebase>.firebaseio.com/Application/'
});

// The url for this model is https://<my-firebase-app>.firebaseio.com/Application/Month1
var month = new Month({
  id: "Month1"
});

month.on('sync', function(model) {
  console.log('Model loaded');
  console.log(model)'
});
```

Comment: I like the look of this. Struggling to get it to work as it's complaining the model must have an ID. Fairly sure a more careful read of the docs will help me.